# How to separate the tags?

Tags: tags

Ok I have searched and can't find. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish.

I want to separate the tags in my post. For example, I want to show the first tag in my post but have all other tags show when you hover over the more button. Now the css and the menu I can handle, but how do I get the tags to separate, like placing the first tag in one div and the rest in another div that is hidden except on hover.

[image]

In the photo above, I want the other tags to appear once they hover over the "+" button.

`<?php the_tags( __( '<span class="tag-links">Tags: ', 'wpbx' ), ", ", "</span>\n" ) ?>`

Comment: Can't you use the `:last-child` in css maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use another function to get the tags, something that returns an object or an array, like that you can manipulate it as you need.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags

```
<?php $my_tags = get_the_tags();?>
```

Then where you need the first tag:

```
<?php echo $my_tags[0]->name?>
```

For looping the rest except the first tag:

```
<?php $count=1;
foreach ($my_tags as $my_tag) {
    if ($count != 1) {?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($my_tag->term_id);?>">
                <?php echo $my_tag->name?>
            </a>
        </li>   
    <?php }
    $count++;
}?>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It isn't linking @Gioia Fueter how do i get it to permalink.

Comment: I will update my answer tomorrow first thing :)

Comment: Ok, and Also It's grabbing all tags I only need it for tags in the post it's attached to.

Comment: Ok, code updated :)

Comment: @RachieVee: You are right about the php shorthand, updated my code too, I know it too but it's a nasty habit ;)

Comment: @user32447: Also, if you gonna work some with wordpress, you should probably get familiar with this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference, as in 90% of the cases it has the answer you are looking for ;)

Comment: @GioiaFueter, i'm looking for this solution as well. I've tried your code, but the tags were not separated by comma. Is there any solution to fix this? Preferable, the comma will stop before last tag.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I based my example from what Gioia has already provided and the example that's on the Codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags).

Also as a tip, you want to avoid using shorthand when writing PHP in WordPress if you're going to stick with [WordPress' best practices](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/#no-shorthand-php-tags), so you always want to write out the opening PHP tag.

I wanted to break out of the foreach for the first tag so you can have an unordered list for the remaining tags and hopefully make styling with CSS easier. If anyone has a nicer way to do this, please let me know. Here's what I have:

```
<?php 
$posttags = get_the_tags();
$count = 0;
if ( $posttags ) {
    foreach( $posttags as $post_tag ) { 

        $count++; //add to counter
        $tag_id = $post_tag->term_id; //get tag id so we can use it for a tag link

        if ( 1 == $count ) {
            echo '<a href="' . get_tag_link($tag_id) . '" class="first-tag">' . $post_tag->name . '</a>';
        } //end of first tag if statement 
        break;// break out of this for each so we can use a ul to separate the tags after the first
    } //end of for each ?>

    <ul class="remaining-tags">
        <?php foreach( $posttags as $remaining_tag ) { 
            $count++; //add to counter
            if ( 2 != $count ) { 
                echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link($tag_id) . '">' . $remaining_tag->name . '</a></li>';
            } // end of if statment for tags after first one
        } //end of for each ?>
    </ul>
<?php } //end of if $posttags ?>
```

Was fighting with the indentation of this on here, let me know if you have trouble reading it. Hope it helps a bit. Also this should work in the loop.

Comment: The permalinks are going to mysite.com instead of mysite.com/tag/tag-name @RachieVee

Comment: Ah, I forgot the permalinks! I'll get to it in a while unless Gioia gets to it first. ;-)

Comment: Updated code that retrieves the tag permalinks. Try now. Also as a tip, you can use var_dump($post_tag) to see what options you have available to you. If you run that command, you'll see where I got ->name and ->term_id. More about var_dump here: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: What I have above works, but I may have a cleaner solution - feel free to use this if it meets your needs, but I'm working with a friend of mine to get a much nicer solution without having to use a break;

Comment: I had to actually combine both of your codes because the first code, somehow didn't show the first tag but it did show the rest and the rest was clickable. The Second code did well as well, but the rest of the tags were linking to only the first tag, so I just combined the two to make it work

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution I got from someone else I know where there's less of the counter in place and uses [unset](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.unset.php) instead. It's just another way to achieve the same thing that I provided, but with less lines of PHP. Also, unset can be dangerous if you want to grab that variable/value somewhere else in the template so only if it fits your circumstances, then it'll work for you.

```
<?php 
        $posttags = get_the_tags();
        $count = 0;
        if ( $posttags ) {
            foreach( $posttags as $key => $post_tag ) {
            $tag_id = $post_tag->term_id; //get tag id so we can use it for a tag link

            if ( 0 === $count ) {
                echo '<a href="' . get_tag_link($tag_id) . '" class="first-tag">' . $post_tag->name . '</a>';
                unset( $posttags[$key] ); //using unset the destroy the variable, unset should only be used if you're not planning to use this first tag anywhere else in the template
                break;// break out of this for each so we can use a ul to separate the tags after the first
            } //end of first tag if statement
        } //end of for each ?>

            <ul class="remaining-tags">
                <?php foreach( $posttags as $remaining_tag ) {
                    echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link($tag_id) . '">' . $remaining_tag->name . '</a></li>';
                } //end of for each ?>
            </ul>
        <?php } //end of if $posttags ?>
```